# Problems on span of col and row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A=cR$ where $c\ne 0$ is a column in $ℝ^m$ and $r\ne 0$ is a row in $ℝ^n$, how do you show that row $A=$span {$r$} and col $A=$ span {$c$}.  (I assume the $R$ is $r$?)

Before answering the question, I am wondering if the size of matrix is $m\times n$ since $c$ is in $ℝ^m$ and $r$ is in $ℝ^n$?

So for this question, what should I start with? Is it span{Col $A$}=$aC_1+...+aC_n$ and span{Row $A$}=$aR_1+...+aR_m$?

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct about the size of $A$. Here’s a hint for the rest: what do the columns/rows of $A$ look like relative to $c$ and $r$?